# Paypal digital goods change cancel url?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using paypal digital goods and it's working great. However it seems I have to specify a cancel url if they click the X or stop buying the product. Instead of it going to a different url can I just send them back to the original page they were at on my site?

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sending them back to where they were if they cancel is the recommended practice for Express Checkout whether you're using DG or not, so that's the URL you would use for the cancel URL.